# concatenate Strings in a view

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How can I concatenate `first_name` and `last_name` and add `honorific_prefix` if it's not empty in `full_name`?

```
defmodule MyApp.UserView do
  use MyApp.Web, :view
  alias MyApp.User

  def full_name(%User{first_name: first_name, 
                      last_name: last_name, 
                      honorific_prefix: honorific_prefix}) do
    first_name
    |> String.upcase
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat those elements as a collection reject the empty ones and join them:

```
[honorific_prefix, first_name, last_name]
|> Enum.reject(&(&1 == ""))
|> Enum.join(" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use `if` and `<>`:

```
def full_name(%User{first_name: first_name, 
                    last_name: last_name, 
                    honorific_prefix: honorific_prefix}) do
  if honorific_prefix == "" do
    ""
  else
    honorific_prefix <> " "
  end <> first_name <> " " <> last_name
end
```